# Is it idiomatic to say "there are 5 Japanese tofus on the dish" to mean "there are 5 pieces of Japanese tofu on the dish"?

Tags: word-usage, articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

When you look for an English noun in an English dictionary, sometimes you see the noun being used as an uncountable and a countable noun. And normally, we use it as an uncountable noun when we want to talk about that noun in general & we use it as a countable noun when we want to talk about that noun specifically.

For example, in the dictionary

> [**cheese**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cheese?q=cheese): [uncountable, countable] a type of food made from milk that can be
>   either soft or hard and is usually white or yellow in colour; a
>   particular type of this food
>
> Cheddar cheese
>
> (British English) goat’s cheese (= made from the milk of a goat)
>
> a cheese sandwich
>
> a piece/slice/block of cheese
>
> I had cheese on toast (= toasted bread covered in melted cheese) for
>   lunch.
>
> a selection of French cheeses

---

So, we say "**I don't eat cheese**" (refer to "**cheese in general**")

But we say "**there are some French cheeses on the dish**" (refer to "**separated cheeses**")

However, "**tofu**" is only an uncountable noun in the dictionary

---

> [**tofu**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tofu?q=tofu) [uncountable] ​a soft white substance that is made from soya and
>   used in cooking, often instead of meat

---

In this case, can we invent our own vocabulary, for example we can use "**tofu**" as a countable noun.

Is it idiomatic to say "**there are 5 Japanese tofus on the dish**"?

If that is not allowed, then we have to say "**there are 5 pieces of Japanese tofu on the dish**", don't we?

Comment: "5 Japanese tofus" implies 5 different types of Japanese tofu, not 5 pieces of the same tofu.

Comment: @nnnnnn, so "5 French cheeses" means 5 types of French cheese?

Comment: Yes, in normal usage.

Comment: You could refer to a *crotte* as a cheese. Five of them (all the same type) on a plate would be *five cheeses*. They have a certain individuality that carries them beyond a mere slice of a larger object.

Comment: "*can we invent our own vocabulary*" The general answer to this question is "No.".